# Redmine Plugin: How to add Project Custom Field

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins

I want to create a Project Custom Field in a plugin. Although running "rake redmine:plugins:migrate RAILS_ENV=production" appears to apply the migration, the project custom field is not created. Here is the migration:

Update: (can't answer my own Question so I'll fix the post with the answer).

```
class PopulateCustomFields < ActiveRecord::Migration
def self.up
  ProjectCustomField.create(:name => 'Estimated time units'; :field_format => 'list', :possible_values => ['Hours', 'Points'], :default_value => 'Hours', :is_required => true, :editable => true, :visible => true)
end
```

(I previously had the wrong syntax for :possible_values, I was using {} instead of [], but no error was reported ).

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have a typo after `'Estimated time units'`. Replace the `';'` by `','`.

You can test your plugin migration script by installing/removing the plugin using the following commands:

- for installing the plugin:

rake redmine:plugins:migrate RAILS_ENV=production

- for uninstalling the plugin:

rake redmine:plugins:migrate NAME=plugin_name VERSION=0 RAILS_ENV=production

Check the [official documentation](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Plugins) for further details.

An example migration script could be like this:

```
class PopulateCustomFields < ActiveRecord::Migration
  # method called when installing the plugin
  def self.up
    if CustomField.find_by_name('A New Custom Field').nil?
      CustomField.create(name: 'A New Custom Field', field_format: 'text')
    end
  end

  # method called when installing the plugin
  def self.down
    CustomField.find_by_name('A New Custom Field').delete unless CustomField.find_by_name('A New Custom Field').nil?
  end
end
```

Check on the redmine database if the custom field 'A New Custom Field' of type 'text' is correctly added/removed when installing/uninstalling the plugin. Also, check that each step has no output errors (see the redmine log as well).